# Grizzly KeepAlive issue with filterchain

Tags: java, keep-alive, grizzly

I've added a Filter to the filterchain in grizzly just before the httpserver filter to limit the amount of http requests that the server has to handle. This works fine until the user adds a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header. If the server cannot handle the request I send a 429 response. The next request of the user goes through the same connection, but it waits for the keepalive timeout of the last request.

My Filter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.Grizzly;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.attributes.Attribute;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.BaseFilter;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainEvent;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.NextAction;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpContent;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpContext;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpEvents.ResponseCompleteEvent;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpPacket;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpRequestPacket;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpResponsePacket;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response;

public class ThrottlingHttpServerFilter extends BaseFilter {
    public AtomicInteger requestsInProgress = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int maximumRequestsInProgress;
    private Logger logger;
    private IThrottlingHook userHook;

    public ThrottlingHttpServerFilter() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ThrottlingHttpServerFilter(Logger logger) {
        this(Integer.MAX_VALUE, logger);
    }

    public ThrottlingHttpServerFilter(int maxNrOfRequests, Logger logger) {
        this(maxNrOfRequests, logger, null);
    }

    public ThrottlingHttpServerFilter(int maxNrOfRequests, Logger logger, IThrottlingHook userHook) {
        if (userHook != null)
            setThrottlingHook(userHook);
        setLogger(logger);
        setMaxNrOfRequests(maxNrOfRequests);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionOccurred(FilterChainContext ctx, Throwable error) {
        super.exceptionOccurred(ctx, error);
        requestsInProgress.decrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public NextAction handleEvent(FilterChainContext ctx, FilterChainEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (event instanceof ResponseCompleteEvent) {
            requestsInProgress.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return ctx.getInvokeAction();
    }

    @Override
    public NextAction handleRead(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException {
        try {
            boolean doWork = false;

            if (requestsInProgress.incrementAndGet() <= maximumRequestsInProgress) {
                doWork = true;
            }

            if (doWork)
                return ctx.getInvokeAction();
            else {

                Object m = ctx.getMessage();
                if (HttpPacket.isHttp(m)) {
                    final HttpContent httpContent = (HttpContent) m;
                    final HttpContext context = httpContent.getHttpHeader().getProcessingState().getHttpContext();

                    Attribute<Request> requestAttribute = Grizzly.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_BUILDER.createAttribute("ThrottlingHttpServerFilter.Request");
                    Request handlerRequest = requestAttribute.get(context);

                    if (handlerRequest == null)
                        handlerRequest = Request.create();
                    else
                        System.out.println("Existing");

                    final HttpRequestPacket request = (HttpRequestPacket) httpContent.getHttpHeader();
                    final HttpResponsePacket response = request.getResponse();

                    requestAttribute.set(context, handlerRequest);
                    Response handlerResponse = handlerRequest.getResponse();
                    handlerRequest.initialize(request, ctx, null);
                    handlerResponse.initialize(handlerRequest, response, ctx, null, null);
                    handlerResponse.setStatus(429, "The server is getting more requests than it can handle. Try again in a few minutes.");
                    handlerResponse.setContentType("text/plain");
                    if (userHook != null)
                        handlerResponse = userHook.buildResponse(handlerRequest, handlerResponse);
                    handlerResponse.finish();
                    requestsInProgress.decrementAndGet();
//<<< I guess here I need to add something.
                    return ctx.getStopAction();
                }
                else 
                    return ctx.getStopAction();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ctx.getStopAction();
        }

    }

    public void setMaxNrOfRequests(int i) {
        this.maximumRequestsInProgress = i;
    }

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void setThrottlingHook(IThrottlingHook hook) {
        this.userHook = hook;
        logger.debug("Throttling hook attached");
    }
}
```

**Result of jmeter**

```
+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|   timeStamp   | elapsed | responseCode |                                   responseMessage                                   |    threadName    |
+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| 1524486302213 |       7 |          429 | The server is getting more requests than it can handle. Try again in a few minutes. | Thread Group 1-2 |
| 1524486302212 |      12 |          200 | OK                                                                                  | Thread Group 1-1 |
| 1524486302224 |      11 |          200 | OK                                                                                  | Thread Group 1-1 |
| 1524486302221 |   30024 |          200 | OK                                                                                  | Thread Group 1-2 |
+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

In the "table" above you can see that the first message on thread 1-2 is rejected because the server is busy with the request from thread 1-1. The connection of 1-2 isn't closed because of keep alive header, but the second message from 1-2 is processed after the timeout of the keepalive (30 seconds). How do I tell my grizzly server that it can start handling the next request? I don't want to close the connection though because that would ignore the keepalive option.